# howto run prepared statements with utf-8 conversion on php/mssql?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

setup:

```
mssql2008RC2, latin-1 encoded
client: php 5.4 utf-8
```

I'm currently using **sqlsrv** and can't move to **PDO** since it lacks the ability to translate between encodings.

The sqlsrv seems to lack the ability to execute prepared statements.

How can I move away from non-prepared statetems?

Comment: What makes you think that SQLSRV cannot execute prepared statements? It even has a [->prepare()](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) method... :-?

Comment: Ah, silly me. (For info: the link says "No version information available, might only be in SVN)" but it's avail in sqlsrv3.0). I'll make a run for it.

Comment: The SVN note shows up in *all* functions from the extension. FYI, you can also use `sqlsrv_query()` to prepare and execute in a single step.

Comment: Ok thanks, in slumber I browsed the functions avaiable for the *mssql* extension... ;-)